# I tried to merge 2 vertices, but it keeps moving to the center

Tags: modifiers, vertices, mirror

I've made 2 different objects at the first time which were 'Body' object and 'Horn' object. And they've already had same Mirror Modifiers of Y Axis, Clipped.

Now I Joined 2 objects to use Ctrl + J. (Horn to Body.)

I Selected 2 vertices from the top of the head like the second picture on the below, press W to tried merge those at the center. But it's moving on to 'Center of the Head'.

I searched on the Google and Blender Manual to solve this issue without question but unfortunately, I still can't find it.

Could you please give me any solutions?

[image]

Comment: Could you post the [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Yeah but how do I attach the files on the thread?

Comment: upload the file with the link above, it will give you a link to the blend file, then edit your question and paste the link

Comment: Could you hold on a minute? I still couldn't find that and I think this would be takes a little bit of time..

Comment: I uploaded my file on the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to the mirror modifier. If the body was made on the right side and the horns on the left, they look ok, but the real vertices are on the opposite sides. Deactivate your mirror's visiblity to check this.

You should work with the "Adjust Edit Cage" of the mirror modifier disabled to avoid creating things hard to merge.
[image: edit cage]

Comment: Thanks for answer for me. I've just checked that and half part of the horn is on the right side.

Comment: same for the body ?

Comment: I added a new picture in my thread. Please check my thread.

Comment: C: Thank you for solve my issue. I just downloaded the file from the answer thread.

Comment: Oh and 1 more thing, can you remove the blender file on the answer thread? It sounds little bit selfish but I don't wanna leak my file to someone.

Comment: Could you explain me how did you merge the horn part? Right now I have the exactly same problem on the ears like before I've got on the horn.